# VBA/Macro : How to read Autocorrect entries from a file other than Normal.dotm (e.g oldNormal.dotm)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, visual-studio-macros

As said,
Normal.dotm: Stores formatted AutoCorrect entries, AutoText entries, keyboard shortcuts, menu customizations, custom toolbars, styles, macros.

I am particularly interested in **formatted** AutoCorrect entries. Lets see as case scenario :

- I am already having 100's of Autocorrect entries in Normal.dotm System-A and System-B.
- I want to add all the Autocorrect entries of System-B to System-A.
- I take/download the Normal.dotm file to System-B, a routine/program in VB/Macro reads AutoCorrect entries from Normal.dotm(from B) and add to Normal.dotm(A).

So in VBA macro we have **Application.Autocorrect.Entries** to access all Autocorrect entries but how to read it from a file other than default "Normal.dotm"

Any other suggestion to programmatically add/copy **formatted** auto correct entries between two systems are also welcome

Thanks in advace

**EDIT**: Useful link(Thanks to James) http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/ExportAutocorrect.htm,  its a docx Macro.
but fails to restore formatted **Tables** precisely. 
e.g a table originally with 5 columns stored/backed up 3 columns(The Macro stores Auto-correct entries in **docx** file as key-value pair) and then at time of restore it fails.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but aren't those settings stored per-user, rather than per template?  In any case, what have you tried and have you looked at the code at http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/ExportAutocorrect.htm?

Comment: @JamesSnell I totally agree settings stored per-user, but still there is one **Normal.dotm** per user and as per Microsoft office people the formatted auto-text entries are captured in it.Thanks but I had tried the mentioned link, its good but for certain tables it fails to restore precisely. I am trying to walk-through the code but as I am not much of VBA guy so getting a hard time. It would be great if someone can throw some suggestion for tools and IDE for "MACRO"(*particularly is it possible to see documentation for a method/object just on mouse hover like we do in eclipse(java Ide)).